# Popup with the content of the exposed date field

Tags: views, 6

I am using "Webform Views Submitted Data" module to show webform submissions report with views. I have one expose filter name "Webform submissions: Submitted" which will give two date options; start date and end date. How do I select the date i want to filter by in a  popup calender?

Comment: Struggling to understand the question. Please can you elaborate

Comment: Could you give more details? I am not sure wether I understand your question correctly, and thus am hesitant to spend time making a longer reply.

Comment: can you give us the id of the textbox that you want it a popup calendar ?? I will post a jQuery snippet that will transform the textbox into a popup calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about writing a custom jquery code with the help of http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker. I am not sure whether you are proficient with jquery , but still i would prefer to have a go at this.

Answer (score 0):

We've been using [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) to have a datepicker in exposed filters. It's fairly straightforward to set up as well. This replies the first question you have, but I am unsure about how the Webform submission is affecting the scenario.

Comment: Updated my question. Tried with better exposed filters but not getting popup option for webform submissions dates.

Comment: BEF gives you popups for Views Exposed Filters, obviously. For webforms, you will have to do something else.